# PooledRedisClientManager not releasing connections

Tags: c#, redis, castle-windsor, servicestack

I am storing lists of json data in redis and accessing it using the ServiceStack c# client.  I am essentially managing my own foreign keys, where I store a `zrange` of ids and I use an interface internal to my application to pull the id's from the `zrange` and then fetch the underlying json objects from Redis and package them as a list to return to other parts of my application.

I am using the `PooledRedisClientManager` as I anticipate Redis to be hosted on a different server from the server executing the code.

I am doing all my development work locally on Windows 8, using the MSOpenTech Redis server.  Currently my biggest challenge is that client connections are not being closed.

My Redis persister is being injected with an instance of `IRedisClientManager` (IoC is CastleWindsor).  This code executes in the context of an azure worker role.

This is how I am fetching items from a zrange:

```
public class MyRedisPersister<T> : IResourcePersister<T>
{ 
    IRedisClientManager _mgr;
    public MyRedisPersister(IRedisClientManager mgr)
    {
        _mgr = mgr;
    }

    public IResourceList<T> Get<T>(string key, int offset, int count) where T
    {
        using (var redis = _clientManager.GetClient())
        {
            var itemKeys = redis.GetRangeFromSortedSet(key, offset, offset + count - 1).ToList();
            var totalItems = redis.GetSortedSetCount(key);

            if (itemKeys.Count == 0)
            {
                return new ResourceList<T>
                    {
                        Items = new List<T>(),
                        Offset = 0,
                        PageSize = 0,
                        TotalItems = 0,
                        TotalPages = 0
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                return new ResourceList<T>
                    {
                        Items = itemKeys.Select(k => redis.Get<T>(k)).ToList(),
                        Offset = offset,
                        PageSize = count,
                        TotalItems = totalItems,
                        TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) totalItems/count)
                    };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to register the `IRedisClientManager`

```
var mgr = new PooledRedisClientManager(100, 10, "localhost:6379");
container.Register(Component.For<IRedisClientsManager>().Instance(mgr).LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Currently my biggest challenge is that client connections are not being closed.**

You are using the 'PooledRedisClientManager' so my understanding is that the client connections should not be closed, just put into the pool for reuse. It looks like your pool size is 100 connections.

You can try using 
`var mgr = new BasicRedisClientManager("localhost:6379")` 
which should dispose of the client.

Comment: Exactly, the concept of a 'pool' is for connections to be re-used and not to be closed until it reaches the `poolSize`.

Comment: duh, so obvious once you said so.  i ratcheted down the number of connections in my pool and everything is working as expected.  Dunno why i was so hung up on that....

Answer (score 2):

*edit* The below approach is not recommended - you should take a dependency on the IRedisClientsManager and wrap all redis client calls inside a using() block, otherwise you **will** be bitten by gremlins.

I've been having similar problems getting Windsor to play nicely with the PooledRedisClientsManager, in the end this seemed to work:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IRedisClientsManager>()
                     .Instance(redisClients)
                     .LifestyleSingleton(),

            Component.For<IRedisClient>()
                     .UsingFactoryMethod(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient(),
                                        managedExternally: true));
    }
```

The managedExternally parameter tells Windsor to not try to apply decommissioning concerns to the IRedisClients and let the PooledRedisClientsManager handle recycling.

Comment: that's nice, saves a bunch of boilerplate code over taking a dependency on IRedisClientManager.

Comment: You're a life-saver, this solved it for me!! I've been debugging problems with our .net => redis setup all day, all because of a missing using() statement :/

Comment: @nover, watch out for some subtle gotchas with the PooledRedisClientsManager. Eg. my repository returns IEnumerable<ViewModel> and inside my using block I return client.As<ViewModel>.Sets["someSet"] - this works fine, but the client attached to the set has been 'disposed' back the pool and will throw odd errors when you try to lazily enumerate the IEnumerable - this only shows up under load.

Comment: @DanB Thx for notifying me about that! Fortunately, my current use of Redis is just as a Message Queue, but i'll keep it in mind if our use should expand :)

Comment: @nover the best reference/documentation is the source code by the way. Keep that to hand.