# Using ServiceStack ICacheClient with Redis and Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, ninject, servicestack

I am using the `ICacheClient` from the servicestack library with Redis as a backend.

I am also using Ninject for DI.

I am trying to figure out in which scope to bind the `PooledRedisClient` manager.

I have tried the following:

```
Bind<ICacheClient>().ToMethod(ctx => new PooledRedisClientManager(redisURI)).InSingletonScope();
```

This seems to work fine but I constantly see `RedisResponseExceptions`.

I am thinking this is due to me running out of connections.

Perhaps SingletonScope in incorrect?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am using servicestack version: 3.9.0

**EDIT**

Is this the correct usage?

```
Bind<ICacheClient>().ToMethod(ctx => new PooledRedisClientManager(redisURI).GetCacheClient()).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: perhaps @mythz can chime in here? I have seen similar questions but could not find a definitive answer

Comment: I just got an email notification from my redis provider saying I was running out of client connection, so I think this is def my issue haha

Comment: You should not run out of connections when registered as a singleton [since all redis access is wrapped in a using block](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.ICacheClient.cs). You likely have another issue unrelated to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Bind<ICacheClient>().ToMethod(ctx => new PooledRedisClientManager(redisURI).GetCacheClient()).InSingletonScope();
```

Not familiar with Ninject syntax but it seems like the above could be creating a new instance of PooledRedisClientManager everytime ICacheClient is resolved? Not sure where 'InSingletonScope' is being applied in the chain.

**Perhaps SingletonScope in incorrect?**

**UPDATE**
Singleton is correct and necessary to get the benefits of pooling the CacheClients. Having a single instance of PooledRedisClientManager containing a collection of CacheClients (the pool) will retrieve existing CacheClients instead of opening new ones. You can limit your pool size by passing in the poolSize parameter in the constructor (default is 10?).

You can also use the BasicRedisClientManager which will not pool the connections and always open and dispose the CacheClient.

<strike>SingletonScope is not correct. My understanding is that if you make your PooledRedisClientManager a Singleton it will never dispose and close the RedisClients it creates.</strike> The idea of a Singleton is to create a single instance (in this case PooledRedisClientManager) that will always be used and not be disposed. Every RedisClient created by your PooledRedisClientManager (by calling GetClient()) will defer the PooledRedisClientManger to dispose of it. Instances of PooledRedisClientManager do not want to dispose of their RedisClients, just put them back in the 'pool' as inactive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Hopefully @mythz can confirm for sure.

Comment: You actually got it right over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14861035/85785 - the RedisClientsManager should be in Singleton scope. It happens that a `PooledRedisClientsManager` also implements `ICacheClient` which should be registered as a singleton since [every operation is wrapped in a using block](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.ICacheClient.cs)

Comment: Updated and hopefully corrected the information in my answer.